# set with compact closure under isometry

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

In a 2nd countable and hausdorff metric space, how to see that the image under an isometry of a subset with compact closure also has compact closure? Thanks.

Comment: Hausdorff is superfluous. All metric spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That was my oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ has compact closure and $T$ is an isometry then the closure of $T(A)$ is $T(\overset {-} A)$. Since $\overset {-} A$ is compact and $T$ is continuous, it follows that the closure of $T(A)$ is compact. [ $T(\overset {-} A) \subset \overset {-} T(A)$ is true for any continuous function and it is easy to prove. Suppose $y \in \overset {-} {T(A)}$. There is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $T(a_n) \to y$. Since $A$ has compact closure the sequence $(a_n)$ lies in a compact set, so it has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$. Let the limit of this subsequence be $a$. Then $a \in \overset {-} {T(A)}$ and $y=\lim T((a_{n_k}) =T(a)$].

Comment: Thank you sir. I should have been more specific in my question. What I failed to understand was exactly why the closure of T(A) is T(closure of A). In general, there is only strict inclusion; how does the isometry work wonders here?

Comment: @X-NautPhD I have added some details.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. It looks to me that the map being isometric has nothing to with the statement. Instead, so long as the map is continuous and the subset has compact closure, the image will then have compact closure. In other words, the strict inclusion becomes an equality if the closure of A is compact. Is that right?

Comment: @X-NautPhD You are right. In fact you don't even need a metric space. What is needed is a continuous map from a topological space to a Hausdorff topological space and a set whose closure is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Extend $T: X \to X$ to $T: c(X) \to c(X)$, where $c(X)$ is the completion of $X$. It's standard that you can do this for isometries.

working in $c(X)$:

$A$ has compact closure iff $A$ is totally bounded and $T$ preserves totally bounded subsets, being uniformly continuous.